# How do I prevent JDialog from showing in gnome-panel(Linux)?

Tags: java, linux, panel, gnome, jdialog

I have a class:

`public class ANote extends JDialog{...}`

In GNOME(Linux) it shows an entry in the gnome-panel. I want it to show nothing (under Windows the instances of JDialog show nothing in the Windows taskbar), because there may be present several instances of the class simultaneously, and this overcrowds the gnome-panel.

How do I prevent it from showing an instance in the gnome-panel?

EDIT: So far I have tried playing with the modality, which hides it from the gnome-panel, but blocks the main frame of the application behind the ANote instances.

EDIT2 - edited the post for clarity

Comment: that's what I would have answered: make it a modal dialog. However, could you explain what you mean with "the same way it does in the taskbar in Windows"?

Comment: By this I mean, that under Windows, the JDialog shows no entries in the taskbar for the ANote instances. Under Gnome, every "new ANote" shows an entry in the gnome-panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a workaround; instead of instantiating the class with:

`new ANote();`

I call the class as:

`JWindow aNoteWindow = new JWindow(new ANote());`

which no more overcrowds the gnome-panel with instances of this class. It also works as expected on Windows XP (no entries in the taskbar).