# java jdialog taskbar button

Tags: java, linux, jframe, taskbar, jdialog

i'm traying a jdialog on linux, but it still appears in my taskbar.
this is the code? what's wrong?

```
import javax.swing.JDialog;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        new mydialog();
    }

    private static class mydialog extends JDialog {
        public mydialog() {
            super();
            setSize(200,200);
            setLocationByPlatform(true);
            setAlwaysOnTop(false);
            setUndecorated(true);
            setVisible(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: could you elaborate your question, perhaps with a screen shot? what do you mean traying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only solution I found is to switch from Swing interfaces to gtk interfaces, to do this I used [java-gnome](http://java-gnome.sourceforge.net/). the only problem is that you must change all components of the swing classes to the corresponding gtk classes.

Answer (score 1):

Since this still seems to be an issue in Linux environments I'd like to share my solution for this topic:

I simply had to create the JDialog with an parent Frame/Window like "new JDialog(new JFrame());" and after setting the JDialog to be Visible I call "jframe.revalidate();". Thats it. Looks like Java has a problem communicating correctly with the DisplayManager while initialising the JDialog..

Works for me with Java 1.8.0.45, Linux Mint 17.1, Cinnamon 2.4.8

Answer (score 0):

try replacing `setLocationByPlatform(true);` with `setLocation(10, 10);`

Comment: in this way you are only say to position the window at the coordinates 10-10 instead of 0-0.
I tried and still does not work.
on windows it works and on Linux it doesn't. i believe that is due to a different implementation of Java jre. I think the problem is unsolvable, unless a low-level intervention in jre classes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use JWindow if you don't want it to appear in the taskbar.
See also: [how-do-i-prevent-jdialog-from-showing-in-gnome-panellinux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439085/how-do-i-prevent-jdialog-from-showing-in-gnome-panellinux)

Comment: JWindow stay always on top, and there are a lot of problems with text dialogs and buttons inside. It's good for splash screen, but i don't believe it's usefull for standard applications.

Answer (score 0):

Been struggling with this one for some time now. What finally worked for me:

```
JDialog frame = new JDialog();
frame.setType(javax.swing.JFrame.Type.POPUP);
```

Alternatively you can try set the type to UTILITY.

Lubuntu 15.04 (LXDE) running Java 1.8.0_25